# Postfix header_checks

Tags: linux, networking, email, postfix

I want to forward a copy of the users email which has the specific subject. I have tried the below settings, able to Redirect that particular subject mail. But I want to forward a copy of that mail to another group id. Instead of REDIRECT is there any option to put a Cc:

in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Then, created /etc/postfix/header_checks and added the following:

```
/^Subject: Time*/
REDIRECT someotheruser@domain.com
```

Answer (score -1):

For Cc separate the addresses with a pipe. For example:

```
a@gmail.com | b@gmail.com
```